# Objective-c Changing UIImagePickerController to video mode

Tags: objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an application which I want onlt to show in the background the video source from the camera. I have the following code in my viewcontroller:

```
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    imagePickerController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    //...
    [self.view addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
    [imagePickerController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [imagePickerController viewDidAppear:YES];
 #endif 
   //...
  [self.view addSubview:otherthings];
```

Then I add other views on top and I have sounds too. However I changed the imagepicker mode to video but it freezes when a sound plays. here's what i changed:

```
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];//initWithRootViewController:self];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    NSArray *videoMediaTypesOnly = [mediaTypes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF contains %@)", @"movie"]];
    BOOL movieOutputPossible = (videoMediaTypesOnly != nil);

    if (movieOutputPossible) {
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = videoMediaTypesOnly;
        imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
        imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        imagePickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;                      
    }


#endif
```

Anyone knows why the camera pickers freezes when a sound plays? The sound is an AVAudioPlayer by the way.

Comment: why did you remove the definition of the rootViewController during alloc?

Comment: Dunno, well after trying it only freezes when I play a sound.Why?

Comment: more than likely you've got something doing an autorelease that you should have alloc'd your own to preserve. Specificly I would start with these two lines: (NSArray *mediaTypes =) and (NSArray *videoMediaTypesOnly =). These are both autoreleased without your control and could cause the problem.

Comment: Even if I delete that and add imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil]; it stil freezes when playing sounds. When the sound ends the camera doesn't unfreeze tho.

Comment: not sure I got that...are you saying movie playback freezes when you are playing an AVAudioPlayer sound and then resumes playback when the sound has finished playing?

Comment: When i play an AVAudioPlayer the camera freezes, and it stays freezed forever. It DOESN'T unfreeze when the audio finishes.

Comment: blerg. well, I'm deleting my answer to clean this up since it didn't work. I'm confused about whether you are playing video or not. It sounds like you just have a live camera view on screen during audio playback. Is that right?

Comment: I just have the live video that the iPhone is displaying at that moment, nothing more.

Comment: i am also having same problem. I used AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId) that plays sound but only if I use [self.videoRecorderController setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear] it doesn't play any sound if I set [self.videoRecorderController setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Use AVFOundation instead of UIImagePickerController.

```
    videoBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];

    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;


    CALayer *viewLayer = videoBackground.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = videoBackground.bounds;
    [videoBackground.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];
    [session startRunning];
    [self.view addSubview:videoBackground];
```